# Copy multiple attachments from list to document library by javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list which each row has at most 1 attachment, and I am trying to copy each attachment from this list to a newly created picture library.

I am able to copy 1 attachment by the following code,

```
var Files;
var myContext;
function CopyAtt(ItemID) {
try {
        myContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var myWeb = myContext.get_site().get_rootWeb(); 

        var folderPath = 'Lists/test/Attachments/' + ItemID;
        var Folder = myWeb.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath);

        Files = Folder.get_files();
        myContext.load(Files);

        myContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(
                                    this, ExecuteCopyOnSuccess),
                                    Function.createDelegate(
                                    this, GetLeadsFail));                       
     }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Line);
    }
}

function GetLeadsFail(sender, args) {
    // Show error message
    alert('GetLeadsFail() failed:' + args.get_message());
}

function ExecuteCopyOnSuccess(sender, args) {
    for (var p = 0; p < this.Files.get_count(); p++) {
        var file = Files.itemAt(p);
        var filename = file.get_name();     
    }       
    if (filename != null) {
            var newUrl = 'PictureLibrary/' + filename;
            file.copyTo(newUrl, true);
            myContext.executeQueryAsync(null, null);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
     CopyAtt(3);
}
```

When I try to call `CopyAtt(ItemID)` multiples times from `$(document).ready`, 
the code is showing errors in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'collectionHasNotBeenInitialized' of undefined
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I suspect that it is related to Files but I cannot find any clues, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Do any of the attachments have apostrophes in their names?

Comment: No, most of them are jpg files with letters name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution several days later, the problem is not related to Files, but  `myContext.executeQueryAsync(null, null);`.

At first I call `CopyAtt(ItemID)` multiple times,

```
    for (i=0; i< Items.Length; i++){
        CopyAtt(Items[i]);
    }
```

`executeQueryAsync()` in `CopyAtt(ItemID)` will break the loop and show errors above.

Rather than for loop, recursion can avoid such errors, and each 
`executeQueryAsync()` will only be executed after one is completed.

```
function CopyAtt(Items, itemIndex) {
try {
        myContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var myWeb = myContext.get_site().get_rootWeb(); 

        var folderPath = 'Lists/test/Attachments/' + Items[itemIndex];
        var Folder = myWeb.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath);

        Files = Folder.get_files();
        myContext.load(Files);

        myContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(
                                this, ExecuteLoadFileSuccess(Items, itemIndex);),
                                Function.createDelegate(
                                this, GetLeadsFail));                       
     }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Line);
    }
}
function GetLeadsFail(sender, args) {
    // Show error message
    alert('Request failed - ' + args.get_message());
}

function ExecuteLoadFileSuccess(Items, itemIndex, sender, args) {

    for (var p = 0; p < this.Files.get_count(); p++) {
        var file = Files.itemAt(p);
        var filename = file.get_name(); 
    }

    if (filename != null) {
            var newUrl = 'PictureLibrary/' + filename;
            file.copyTo(newUrl, true);
            myContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(
                                    this, function(){ExecuteCopyOnSuccess(Items, itemIndex);}),
                                    Function.createDelegate(
                                    this, GetLeadsFail));
    }
}

function ExecuteCopyOnSuccess(Items, itemIndex, sender, args) {
    //Call CopyAtt() after copy files success.
    if (itemIndex <Items.length-1) {
    CopyAtt(Items, itemIndex+1);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
       //save all Items ID in an array.
       var Items = [2,3,6,7,8,10];
       CopyAtt(Items, 0);
}
```

Comment: do you know how can it copy to another list rather than document library.